# Spring boot application works with IntelliJ, however fails with NoSuchMethodError while running with gradle bootRun

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

My spring boot application works perfectly while executed from IntelliJ Idea, however when I try to run it with bootRun it complies, but throws `NoSuchMethodError` while executing.

build.gradle file is listed below.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = "16"

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.salesforce-marketingcloud:fuelsdk:1.6.0'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.7.2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.7.2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.7.2'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_16
```

Also the stacktrace of the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.codehaus.stax2.ri.EmptyIterator org.codehaus.stax2.ri.EmptyIterator.getInstance()'
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.OutputElementBase.getPrefixes(OutputElementBase.java:358) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.writeStartElement(StaxUtils.java:789) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:737) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:701) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.copy(StaxUtils.java:625) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractLoggingInterceptor.writePayload(AbstractLoggingInterceptor.java:168) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor$LoggingCallback.onClose(LoggingOutInterceptor.java:249) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:209) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:652) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277) ~[cxf-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy88.retrieve(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSoapObject.retrieve(ETSoapObject.java:350) ~[fuelsdk-1.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSoapObject.retrieve(ETSoapObject.java:173) ~[fuelsdk-1.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSoapObject.retrieve(ETSoapObject.java:149) ~[fuelsdk-1.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.retrieve(ETClient.java:630) ~[fuelsdk-1.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETClient.retrieve(ETClient.java:569) ~[fuelsdk-1.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.example.sfmcbackend.service.DERetrievalService.getDataExtensionByName(DERetrievalService.java:18) ~[main/:na]
```

I've checked the classpath both runtime and compile and all of the dependecies are there, as well as the dependency which is causing the error.

Comment: There is not enough info here, did you try uncommenting the bootjar task? What does your main Application class look like? 

I highly recommend you use the spring boot initializer online to see what an application and Gradle file should look like to run with the bootRun task. https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Try to give more informations about the method which causes the errors. 
Have you changed a version of a dependency ? This may cause the error, because gradle will rebuild the project while intellij may skip this part

Comment: @SpeedyTheSnail I've used Spring Initializr for this project. Commented bootRun task is due to some answers I tried to apply from the internet, it does not compile with this directive at all

Comment: @KASMIG. I've added the stacktrace. However I once changed versions to latest, and than rolled back. If this might affect something can you tell how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method which causes the error is this
https://javadoc.io/doc/org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api/latest/index.html

Check the documentation for the version you're using, maybe there is no getInstance method in that version.
I don't see any reference to that dependency in your gradle file, it is probably imported by one of your dependencies. I'm not an expert with gradle, but you can try  the gradle equivalent for `mvn tree` to get all the infos.
If you find out that the version does not have getInstance method, you can import it manually with excluding the version imported by your dependency.

Once again this a solution i used with maven, but i assume gradle offers similar functionnalities.

Comment: Thanks, the alternative for `mvn tree` is 'gradle dependency' and it helped a lot.
The main problem occured due to `fuelsdk` having dependencies that were depening on the same package of different version. Perhaps in the newer one the method was deprecated, but the problem was solved by forcing the oldest version that was required by the dependencies.

Comment: While Im glad that this worked out - why did it work with IntelliJ in the first place?
How does IntelliJ handle dependencies differently?